# error: connection reset by peer

Tags: networking, ssh, redhat

I have 2 virtual machines, running RHEL6, on softlayer (both have private IP address), I can ssh to machine B from machine A but when I try to ssh from machine B to machine A, I get this error: `ssh: connect to host 10.66.98.160 port 22: Connection refused` 
`sshd` service is running on both machines.

Comment: Could be firewall, SSH configuration, or the wrong IP being used.  You'll need to provide all that information, and preferably pcaps, in order for us to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Connection Refused generally means that nothing is listening on the IP:Port so in your case it appears that sshd is not listening on 10.66.98.160 port 22.

Check the configuration of sshd and ensure that the Listen directive is correct for your requirements.

Answer (score -1):

[Here's](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205179/ssh-problem-read-from-socket-failed-connection-reset-by-peer) someone with the same question on Ubuntu's forum.

If that doesn't fix the issue you can look at more detailed output by adding -v -vv or -vvv to the ssh command for level 1, 1-2, or 1-3 debug output when you try to make the connection.